# Prove that when $F$ is a field, $F[x_1 , x_2]$ is not a principal ideal ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra

This question is from Herstein’s *Topic in Algebra*, page 166, question No. 8.

> Prove that when $F$ is a field, $F[x_1 , x_2]$ is not a principal ideal ring.

I didn't understand, as no answer has been given in this post: 
[Prove that it is not a Principal Ideal Ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1618903/prove-that-it-is-not-a-principal-ideal-ring)

Any hints/solution will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54206/if-f-is-a-field-then-fx-y-is-a-principal-ideal-domain)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:

$F[x_1,x_2]$ is not a principal ideal ring if you can find an ideal that cannot be generated by a single element. Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $$(x_1,x_2)=(f)$$ What can you say about $f$?

**Strong hint**:

> $x_1,x_2\in (f)\Rightarrow f=x_1x_2g\Rightarrow (x_1,x_2)\subseteq (x_1x_2)$. From here, consider what happens with the ideals under the evaluation homomorphism $$\phi: F[x_1,x_2]\rightarrow F\\x_1\mapsto 1\\x_2\mapsto 0$$